# failed to fetch 403 forbidden & 404 not found on ubuntu focal

Tags: apt

Trying to install various packages using `apt` but face 403 & 404 error codes while installing them even though I have 2 other devices that fetches packages normally (not same device type).

Some information:

1. Laptop is old with a Pentium `x86_64`
2. Tried to switch sources list from `software & updates` (Tried main, US & mirrors) but to mo avail).
3. I am facing same problem with `firefox`, `openjdk-8-jdk` and many others.
4. faced the problem with `python3-pip` but running `sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pip` after switching to mirrors seemed to solve it (yet it didn't for the rest).
5. Tried different ISP but to no avail.
6. Tried `$ sudo apt install --fix-missing && sudo apt install openjdk-8jdk` but gives the same output.
7. Tried jdk11 but gives exactly same error output.

This is the full log:

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libgif7 libice-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev
  libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless x11proto-core-dev x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  default-jre libice-doc libsm-doc libx11-doc libxcb-doc libxt-doc openjdk-8-demo openjdk-8-source visualvm icedtea-8-plugin fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-wqy-microhei fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libgif7 libice-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev
  libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless x11proto-core-dev x11proto-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 39.5 MB/43.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 162 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt Mirrorlist [528 B]                                                                                                         
Ign:5 http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                                      
Ign:2 http://ubuntu.dts.mg/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                                   
Ign:3 http://ubuntu.dts.mg/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                                            
Ign:4 http://ubuntu.dts.mg/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                                   
Ign:3 http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                                      
Ign:4 http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                             
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                                       
Ign:4 https://mirrors.united.cd/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                              
Ign:3 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                                  
Ign:4 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                   
Ign:5 https://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                                        
Ign:3 https://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:3 https://mirrors.united.cd/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 https://mirrors.united.cd/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                                                       
Ign:3 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04                          
Ign:2 https://mirror.wiru.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 https://mirror.wiru.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:4 http://deb-mirror.habari.co.tz/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:3 http://deb-mirror.habari.co.tz/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 http://deb-mirror.habari.co.tz/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:4 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:4 https://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:4 https://mirror.wiru.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:3 https://mirror.hostafrica.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:3 https://mirror.wiru.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:4 http://mirror.aptus.co.tz/pub/ubuntuarchive focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:3 http://ubuntu.mirror.rain.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:4 http://ubuntu.mirror.rain.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 http://download.nust.na/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 https://mirror.hostafrica.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 http://ubuntu.dts.mg/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 http://mirror.lnx-solutions.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:3 http://download.nust.na/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:4 http://download.nust.na/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:5 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:4 http://mirror.lnx-solutions.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Err:4 https://mirror.hostafrica.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 41.188.34.241 80]
Ign:3 http://mirror.aptus.co.tz/pub/ubuntuarchive focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
Err:2 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 41.188.34.241 80]
Err:5 https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 155.232.191.230 80]
Err:3 http://mirror.lnx-solutions.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 41.188.34.241 80]
Fetched 528 B in 51s (10 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.united.cd/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 41.188.34.241 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.lnx-solutions.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 41.188.34.241 80]
E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.hostafrica.co.za/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 41.188.34.241 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.aptus.co.tz/pub/ubuntuarchive/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk_8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 155.232.191.230 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David focal fosa

Comment: @David I tried with a live ubuntu to install it, first time it gave me the same error, second time (after `sudo apt update` it installed successfully) yet it isn't doing the same with the current system installation

Comment: Tested with `https://mirrors.united.cd/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb` which indeed does not exist on that server. Your local package database is stale and needs to be updated. Run `sudo apt update` to do so, and read your output carefully for errors that would prevent updating your local database. This is precisely why most reputable instructions begin with an apt update.

Comment: @user535733 no doubts i did +100 times `sudo apt update`

Comment: Did you read the `apt update` output for errors? We don't know, since it's not in your question.

Comment: @user535733 not a single error

Comment: "Err:4 mirror.hostafrica.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04 404 Not Found [IP: 41.188.34.241 80]" is an error of an unreachable repo. Try different mirrors in the Software & Updates.